# TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'float'> when using exp function

Tags: python, pandas, types, typeerror

I have dataframe "subset" which is the first 50 columns of a larger dataframe. I am trying to use the exp function on a number formed by dividing the value of one column by the value in another column:

```
import math
subset['exp'] = math.exp(subset['A'] / subset['B'])
```

However this returns the following error:

```
TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'float'>
```

I am confused because both columns are float types which I have tested using:

```
df['A'].dtype
```

I have even tried converting them using the float function (even though they appear to be floats already):

```
 subset['exp'] = math.exp(float(subset['A']) / float(subset['B']))
```

But this produces the same error!

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`math.exp()` expects a single floating point number, and you pass a Series instead. Use `numpy.exp()` (a vectorized version of `math.exp()`).

Answer (score 1):

Like DYZ pointed out, you could use `numpy` and get the following result:

```
subset['exp'] = np.exp(subset['A'] / subset['B'])
```

Also, if you would like to stay with `math.exp`, you could go with `apply`

```
subset['exp'] = subset.apply(lambda x: math.exp(x.A / x.B), axis=1)
```

`apply` loops through the rows or your `dataframe`. However, this method would not be the fastest in the case of a large `dataframe`.